# TV show with a boy who uses a sandglass to stop time

Tags: story-identification, tv

Broadcasting Period:1990s

Key Items: sandglass

Main character:boy

Contents: They fight with the enemy for the magic sandglass that controls time.

The boy uses the power of the sandglass to freeze his enemy's time and win.

Last scene, the boy is scolded by a woman. The girl sitting next to him is laughing.  The boy uses the power of the sandglass to stop time for the woman and the girl and then walk away from the place

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was this part of a series or a standalone show/TV movie?

Comment: Thanks for comment.
From my memory, I think it's part of a TV series.

Comment: Animated or live action? If the sandglass is part of a dagger, could potentially be Prince of Persia: Sands of Time...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It was live action. I don't think it was Prince of Persia. The main character was a little boy. I also think there was a man with an eye patch as villans.